# Getting events from Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am currently trying to get and parse events of a user by making use of the Facebook api. In order to do this, I am making use of the function below.

```
function facebook_get_events($facebookSession) {

        // make the API call and get array of event objects
        $events = (new FacebookRequest($facebookSession, 'GET', '/me/events')->execute()->getGraphObject();

        log("Got events from facebook " . count($events));

        foreach ($events as $event) {
           echo $event->getProperty('id');
        }

        return events;
}
```

**Problem:** The problem is that its not working. In the log I am noticing that only one element is in the array. By the way, I am assuming that events is an array because, according to Facebook's documentation, the response is "an array of Event objects". [Click here to check out the doc link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/events).

With regards to the printing of the id, nothing is being shown.

In order to check whether the request is correct, I also used Facebook's Graph API Explorer, and it is returning the list of events correctly. The result structure is shown below (Information has been removed due to privacy concerns).

```
    {
      "data": [
        {
          "name": "...", 
          "start_time": "...", 
          "location": "...", 
          "rsvp_status": "...", 
          "id": "..."
        }, 
        {
          "name": "...", 
          "start_time": "...", 
          "timezone": "...", 
          "rsvp_status": "...", 
          "id": "..."
        }
      ], 
.....
}
```

I have also checked whether my permissions are correct, and I can confirm that I am including the user_events permission. I think my issue is more related on how I am parsing the response.

As requested by a comment, I have also done a var_dump on events. The following is a snapshot of what I received.

> ```
> object(Facebook\GraphObject)#5 (1) {
> ["backingData":protected]=>
> array(2) {
> ["data"]=>
> array(25) {
> [0]=> object(stdClass)#6 (5) {
> ["id"]=> string(15) “…”
> ["name"]=> string(11) “..”.
> [“location"]=> string(14) “…”
> ["start_time"]=> string(24) “…”
> ```

**Progress 1:**

I also tried making use of this code, calling the 'data' property, but still did not manage.

```
function facebook_get_events($facebookSession) {

        // make the API call and get array of event objects
        $events = (new FacebookRequest($facebookSession, 'GET', '/me/events')->execute()->getGraphObject();

        log("Got events from facebook " . count($events->getProperty('data')));

        foreach ($events->getProperty('data') as $event) {
           echo $event->getProperty('id');
        }

        return events;
}
```

The above code prints out nothing.

Comment: Would you show us what you see when you `var_dump($events)` right after the execute call please? Hopefully this will clear up if it's definitely how you're parsing it and the format it's in. Maybe it needs something like `foreach ($events['data]) {` or whatever.

Comment: I placed the var_dump in the question. Thank you

Comment: Got a Warning : PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Providing a proper answer now.

Comment: Is you facebook application currently in sandbox mode? In that case you are only able to get events from your own user or the administrator user of that application. Applications will only share information about other users when you have put the app out of sandbox

Comment: Yes I am in sandbox mode and I am getting the events of the administrator. If you look at my var_dump screen shot, I am getting the events. The problem is how to parse them, iterate each one and print out its details....

Answer (score 2):

This is the easiest way to go:

```
$eventResponse = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me/events'))->execute()->getResponse();
$events = $eventResponse->data;

foreach ($events as $event) {
    echo $event->name;
    //echo $event->id;
    //echo $event->name;
    //echo $event->start_time;
    //echo $event->timezone;
    //echo $event->location;
}
```

---

And this is the nice way:

Class declarations:

```
class GraphEventlist extends GraphObject implements Iterator 
{
    /**
     * @var GraphEvent[]
     */
    protected $backingData = array();

    public function __construct($raw)
    {
        foreach ($raw['data'] as $eventArray) {
            if ($eventArray instanceof \stdClass) {
                $eventArray = get_object_vars($eventArray);
            }
            $this->backingData[$eventArray['id']] = $eventArray;
        }
    }

    public function current()
    {
        return $this->getProperty(key($this->backingData), 'GraphEvent');
    }

    public function key()
    {
        return key($this->backingData);
    }

    public function next()
    {
        next($this->backingData);
    }

    public function rewind()
    {
        reset($this->backingData);
    }

    public function valid()
    {
        return null !== key($this->backingData);
    }
}

class GraphEvent extends GraphObject
{
}
```

Get events

```
$events = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me/events'))->execute()->getGraphObject('GraphEventlist');
```

Iterate:

```
foreach ($events as $event) {
    echo $event->getProperty('name');
}
```

Get single event by ID:

```
var_dump($events->getProperty('6499**********4', 'GraphEvent'));
```